# Gradient generator for android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any tool present which can generate gradient in xml format for android apps? It is difficult for me to create a good gradient without visualizing the result immediately (like 'graphical layout' for layout xmls).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's [angrytools.com/gradient](http://angrytools.com/gradient/) can create gradient xml code for android apps

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Abhijeet's answer I was able to find this:

http://angrytools.com/android/button/

It shows the XML code for creating a drawable.

Comment: in my browsers the gradient doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works on the latest Firefox with default settings such as JavaScript enabled. The issue could be that your browser is outdated or doesn't support CSS gradients. Does the code it generates work in your application? The tool is most likely in active development, so you could contact the site owner and let them know what browser and OS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use online shapes generator for Android and choose background -> gradient.
Online tools: [Android online shapes generator](http://shapes.softartstudio.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColorPicker to set various colors in the gradient.xml programatically and see the result immediately.